# Annoying Blue Color for Button in HTML

Tags: button, hyperlink, underline

[Screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IirMt.jpg)
I am trying to get rid of this annoying blue color in my Bootstrap button supported with Bootstrap. First, there was an underline with blue color, but when add `text-decoration: none` underline is cleared but still blue color.

```html
<style type="text/css">
      a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
      </style>



      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/freyahomebodrum_mertticaret/"
              target="_blank">Instagram</a>
          </button>
```

But I still have the blue color as in the screenshot. I have tried variations using span but that does not help either. Am I doing something wrong above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this change the color property of anchor tag like this.

```
a{
 color: #000; /* this will change the color to black
}
```

Comment: This worked very well, but why text-decoration: none; is not worked in this case. Thank you

Comment: because text-decoration property is used for decorating line like underline, overline under the text not for coloring the text for that we use color property, and if you use text-decoration-color property it will color the line not text.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply `class="btn btn-outline-dark"` to the `<a>` tag itself, removing the `<button>` altogether. Bootstrap's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-tags) includes an example with `<a>`.